# Synchronous HttpPost on a separate thread

Tags: android

Im currently posting some data to a php webservice using a class that extends `AsyncTask`.

Now i need to make a synchronous call, because i want to show the default exception popup that my app has crashed once the data is sent (`previousHandler.uncaughtException(t, e)`).

Can i just disable the async functionality on the `AsyncTask`, or do you have any other suggestions

Here is my current code, thanks in advance:

```
public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {

    final Writer result = new StringWriter();
    final PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(result);
    e.printStackTrace(printWriter);
    String stacktrace = result.toString();
    printWriter.close();

    String deviceUuid = Utilities.DeviceUuid(ctx, cr);
    String bluetoothName = Utilities.LocalBluetoothName();

    AsyncTasks.ErrorLogTask logTask = new AsyncTasks.ErrorLogTask(e, bluetoothName, deviceUuid, stacktrace);
    logTask.execute();

    //task wont be complete before this code below runs since its async.

    previousHandler.uncaughtException(t, e);


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you still need to catch the exception.  I would keep the call in your AsyncTask, but catch the exception.  Either use a flag as the return value from `doInBackground` or create a variable local to the AsyncTask to use as a flag, and in your `onPostExecute` check for the flag and show a dialog if necessary.

In general you don't want to make a server call on the main UI thread because of the risk of ANRs.  See this article on them:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/responsiveness.html

Answer (score 0):

Put your default exception popup into `onPostExecute()` method of the `ErrorLogTask`. That block executes in main thread when your task is finished.